# helm list not showing up after terraform apply

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am using terraform helm provider to install helm package.

My current main.tf file

```
  provider "helm" {

  kubernetes {
        config_path = pathexpand(var.kube_config)
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = pathexpand(var.kube_config)
}


data "template_file" "test_values" {
        template = file("./scripts/test-values.yml")

        vars = {
          NAMESPACE = "test"
        }
}

resource "helm_release" "test" {
  chart = "test"
  name = "test"
  repository = "."
  namespace = "test"

  values = [
        data.template_file.test_values.rendered
  ]
}
```

Kubectl command output

```
 kubectl get pods -n test 
   NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
   test                                0/1     Running   0          59m
```

Issue is "helm list" does not show any result.
My current version

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.17.0", GitCommit:"a690bad98af45b015bd3da1a41f6218b1a451dbe", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.17.0", GitCommit:"a690bad98af45b015bd3da1a41f6218b1a451dbe", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

and terrafrom version -

```
provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.69.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm v2.1.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v2.2.0
```

Any reason why "helm list" does not show any output ?

Comment: That is a super old version of Helm. Have yout tried upgrading to see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: @MattSchuchard -> I update to helm3 version. Still same issue

Comment: Just to confirm, did you set your kube context to the "test" namespace before you run `helm list`? What's the exact command that you're using? As a test, maybe you can run `helm list -A` to get the helm releases in all namespaces (provided your cluster is not too large) as a sanity check.

Comment: helm list -A shows the ouput but not helm list.